# How to calculate the file size downloaded and the total data to be downloaded in Java?

Tags: java

How to calculate the amount of data downloaded and the total data to be downloaded in Java?
E.G. 12kb/130kb...110kb/130kb

Answer (score 2):

If you mean downloading files via http using `URLConnection`, then you can

- get the `Content-Length` response header to get the total size. This is done via `connection.getContentLength()`
- to get the already downloaded amount, just count the bytes you have processed from the stream.

Comment: Just make sure that the Content-Length header is set. I have found if you are calling custom servlets you need to set the header in the response.

Comment: @Bozho I have the same problem in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349296/implement-pause-resume-in-file-downloading, Can you take a look?

Answer (score 2):

To get amount of data that has been downloaded you can use
CountingInputStream from Apache Commons IO. See
http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html
Wrap your stream in it.

To get total length you need to use information from the server. For example,
Content-Length header as previously mentioned. But it only works for http.
It may not always be possible in generic case.